# Android - findViewById(R.id.list) returns null

Tags: android, android-activity, listactivity

I have a class that is called when my app launches.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements NetworkEvent.
```

In this situation,

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

works perfectly. However if I then call a new intent via:

```
   String[] names = object.names();
```

Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SimpleList.class);
   myIntent.putExtra("names", names);
   startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

where SimpleList is defined as:

```
public class SimpleList extends ListActivity implements NetworkEvent
```

then when I call

```
   list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Log.i("MyApp", "List:" + list);

from within the SimpleList class, list is null :(

How come? Both classes are within the same package.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why it is happening in your case, but the `ListView` in your layout XML, must be defined as `<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"`, not the typical `<ListView android:id="@+id/list"`. If your class extends `ListActivity`,  in that case, you just use `getListView()` to access the list.
Check out this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Comment: Does not work when ListView is initialized in a child of FragmentActivity. Same null object returned.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you call `setContentView(R.whatever)` before you can find any ids in it.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar case, `findViewById` stopped working for me after adding a `LinearLayout` view.

The solution was to also add the following:

`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

to LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Add

"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

to your listView, for example:

```
<LinearLayout  
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">  

  <TextView 
    android:text="test"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="40dp">
  </TextView>

  <ListView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">     
  </ListView>  

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to mention what my problem was. In my XML, I had assigned `android:name="@+id/bob"` instead of `android:id="@+id/bob"`, but because of the @+id, it was still registering it as an intellisensable field.